# Null check in formula column

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am usable formula column in grails:

```
 static mapping = {
        id generator: 'uuid'
        version false
        merchantTotal formula: "total_amount - penalty_fee"
```

Domain:

```
class Transaction {
    ....
    ............
    @Transient
    BigDecimal merchantTotal
```

The problem with above is that if any one row has "null" value in penalty_fee column then the total value of expression would be returned as null. I want to apply a null check or treat the null values as 0 in formula column.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says, that the formula field is plain sql.
Would a mapping like

```
merchantTotal formula: "total_amount - IFNULL(penalty_fee, 0)"
```

help?